# How to prevent BeginGetResponse to be performed on a thread pool

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, httpwebresponse

My desktop .NET 3.5 application uses `WebRequest.BeginGetResponse` to issue a request which is used to implement long polling. This request typically takes 10 seconds or more to process. The trouble is `BeginGetResponse` performs the waiting for the request to complete on the thread pool, which then seems to be starving. Is there some way how to specify a custom thread or a custom thread for `BeginGetResponse` to use?

As an alternative I could also use my own thread performing synchronous request using `WebRequest.GetResponse` (hopefully this is [really synchronous in .NET 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163880.aspx), it [was not in .NET 1.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/mreynolds/archive/2003/09/06/26567.aspx)), but then I have a problem I am unable to terminate the request prematurely when I need to quit the application, as I see no clean way how to abort a synchronous request.

Comment: It seems I was wrong in diagnosing the problem. The problem was not (or not only) the thread pool starvation, but rather [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7627892/16673).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you're using WPF or Windows forms.. Here's a WPF Example.

```
        WebRequest w = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");

        Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                WebResponse response = w.GetResponse();
                dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {

                    // Handle response on the dispatcher thread.

                }), null);
            }));

        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
```

Notice the IsBackground = true. So your application will terminate it on exit.
It's also possible to put HttpWebRequest.Create inside the thread method.

Windows.Form equivalent

```
        WebRequest w = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");

        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                WebResponse response = w.GetResponse();
                this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {

                    // Handle response on the dispatcher thread.

                }), null);
            }));

        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
```

Where *this* is a Form/Control

Comment: I am using WinForms. I am not familiar with WPF, however your code does not seem to be WPF specific, or am I missing something? Both Thread and Dispatcher seem to be available without WPF. Looks promising, will give it a try.

Comment: The dispatcher isn't used in Windows.Forms, so I think you could invoke on the dispatcher and on first call a dispatcher object will be created, but it won't be invoked because that dispatcher isn't running. (like a message loop)

Comment: Actually this is in a background thead, with no need to any UI reponse. It therefore shows in my case I can simply use a synchronouse WebRequest.GetResponse and mark my background thread with IsBackground = true, and I then do not have to worry about it not terminating soon enough.