# How can I do parallel processing inside foreach loop for "requestData"?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I am iterating one `foreach loop` in which I am parsing one string like this:

I want to fire parallel request in `HttpWebRequest` for my string "`imageUrl`". Means At a time 4 request and response type of system.(For Utility of my Core).

How can I do it?

**Code:**

```
foreach (var item in requestData)
{

    try
    {
        string imageUrl = Convert.ToString(item.ImageUrl);
        imageUrl = imageUrl.Replace('\r', ' ');
         //It is Use for saving at our project location.
        string saveLocation = 
               @AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Image\someone.jpg";

        byte[] imageBytes;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest imageRequest = 
                                (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imageUrl);
            WebResponse imageResponse = imageRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = imageResponse.GetResponseStream();
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(responseStream))
            {
                imageBytes = br.ReadBytes(500000);
                br.Close();
            }
            responseStream.Close();
            imageResponse.Close();

            FileStream fs = null;
            BinaryWriter bw = null;
            fs = new FileStream(saveLocation, FileMode.Create);
            bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
            bw.Write(imageBytes);

            fs.Close();
            bw.Close();
            id = Convert.ToString(item.Id);
            // string ImageUrl= Convert.ToString(dr["ImageUrl"]);
            ImageProcess(id);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            log.Info("Image Url Wrong!!!");
            drCurrentRow = dt.NewRow();
            drCurrentRow["Id"] = Convert.ToString(item.Id); ;
            drCurrentRow["Label"] = "Error";
            drCurrentRow["Score"] = 0;
            drCurrentRow["Flag"] = "1";
            dt.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
            //drCurrentRow = dt.NewRow();
            dt.AcceptChanges();
        }

        finally
        {
            fs.Close();
            bw.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Info(e);
    }              

}
BulkInsert();
}
```

I want to fire parallel request in `HttpWebRequest` for my string `imageUrl`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send multiple WebRequest in Parallel.For](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477261/send-multiple-webrequest-in-parallel-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Parallel.ForEach(requestData, item =>
    {
      //your code 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Parallel.ForEach()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx) or [by Using async and await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674880.aspx)

```
Parallel.ForEarch(requestData, item => {

  //web request

});
```